# fatal: Could not read from remote repository Laravel Forge

Tags: github, ssh-keys, forge

Getting this error while deploying but able to commit and push code. 
I've deleted previous developer repository after that this problem is occurring. I tried to generate new ssh key at server then added it to new repository but github showing **key is already in use** message.

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

How can I resolve this problem? I just want to use my new repository for deployment.

Answer (score 3):

You can go through the list of common causes listed in "[**Solving common public key problems in Laravel Forge**](https://medium.com/@nash_32562/solving-common-public-key-problems-in-laravel-forge-a-k-a-e2e1eb84e0fa)"  from Nash:

- Forge should be able to access your server

  - the key should be registered in `Servers -> YOUR SERVER -> Server Details -> Meta -> Forge's Public Key`
  - *and* you need to SSH into your server and add this key to both the `/home/forge/.ssh/authorized_keys` file and the `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.
- Your server should be able to access your Git repo.
  Your server’s public key needs to be added to your Git repository service (e.g. GitHub, Bitbucket).
- Your computer should be able to access your Git repo AND your server
  Check your own `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

See also "[forge-docs / SSH Keys](https://github.com/laravel/forge-docs/blob/master/1.0/accounts/ssh.md)".

Comment: I'm trying to add server's public key to git repo but it is showing error that ```key is alraedy in use```

Comment: @vartikasharma so it is already added: the issue does not come from that end (GitHub repo), but possibly from Forge or your computer.

Comment: I have added my system's  key  ```users->profile->sshkey ,  server->sshkey``` but still getting permission denied issue

Comment: @vartikasharma By key, you mean the Forge’s public key? And is it added in the target server to both the `/home/forge/.ssh/authorized_keys` file and the `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` file? I mean this is not just about GitHub.

Comment: Yes Forge's Public Key is added at both the places

Comment: How Do I update server's public key. I have generated a new id_rsa key for server but server's public key is same as before

Comment: @vartikasharma My answer (and the linked article https://medium.com/@nash_32562/solving-common-public-key-problems-in-laravel-forge-a-k-a-e2e1eb84e0fa) suggest: Servers -> YOUR SERVER -> Server Details -> Meta -> Forge's Public Key

Comment: @vartikasharma If you are talking about the target server, you only need to update the authorized_key files mentioned in the answer. Not the public key itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214725/discussion-between-vartika-sharma-and-vonc).